# How to reset Microsoft Edge in Ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft-edge

The account is not removed.  How can I remove them as a new browser?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evbun.png)

I want to reset all data in Ms. Edge Ubuntu as a new version on my desktop. I uninstall and re-install it. But somehow the old data is still there. You can see it in the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling a program wont delete your data stored in the system. Sometimes you need to delete it manually. Microsoft Edge stores its user data in a folder, which can be found in the following location in Ubuntu: `~/.config/Microsoft/Edge` . You can delete this folder to remove your data
Run this command to delete all your config files

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Edge
```

**Method 2**

You can also use the browser itself to delete your personal data.This can be done by going to the settings menu and clear the browsing data.

Comment: I try to use cmd "rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Edge" and "rm -rf ~/.config/microsoft-edge" as you suggest. But somehow, it's still not work.

Comment: what is the output??  Also u can use the second method.

Comment: Thank you for supporting. I get a new advice from him https://stackoverflow.com/a/75459313/19549317. So I resolved the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, I assume that you wouldn't like to see the "Choose an account" dropdown menu. Actually, it has nothing to do with your old data (or it does not mean "old data" was preserved), but has something to do with the **accounts set to be used by other apps**. You may find it in your system settings, where you've connected this Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

delete file(this file contains info about your microsoft account) in this dirrectory:
/.cache/Microsoft/Edge/IdentityCache/OneAuth/accounts

Comment: Thank you. I belive this is a great solution to resolve my issue, so I try it. It works! <3